# What does this code below do ? In r language

Tags: r

```
#Read state of union file
speech<-readLines("stateoftheunion1790-2012.txt")
head(speech)
```

What does this code below do after it reads the file ??? I was told It will give a list where each entry is the text between consecutive ***'s. But what does that mean.

```
x <- grep("^\\*{3}", speech)
list.speeches <- list()
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  if(i == 1){
    list.speeches[[i]] <- paste(speech[1:x[1]], collapse = " ")
  }else{
  list.speeches[[i]] <- paste(speech[x[i-1]:x[i]], collapse = " ")}
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't do _anything_ unless it's applied to data in a specific format. We don't have your data, so we can't say what the code will do to your data. Please help us to help you by providing a reproducible example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! As @Allan Cameron pointed out, whenever you ask questions, especially if you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()`. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

I've detailed each part of the code with coding comments. Feel free to ask questions if you've got any.

```
speech <- readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jdwilson4/Intro-Data-Science/master/Data/stateoftheunion1790-2012.txt")
head(speech) # print the first 6 rows captured in the object speech
# [1] "The Project Gutenberg EBook of Complete State of the Union Addresses,"
# [2] "from 1790 to the Present"                                             
# [3] ""                                                                     
# [4] "Character set encoding: UTF8"                                         
# [5] ""                                                                     
# [6] "The addresses are separated by three asterisks"                        

x <- grep("^\\*{3}", speech) 
# searches speech char vector for indices coinciding with strings of 3 asterisks ***

list.speeches <- list() # create a list to store the results
for(i in 1:length(x)){  # for each index that coincided with three asterisks
  if(i == 1){           # if it's the first set of asterisks ***
    list.speeches[[i]] <- paste(speech[1:x[1]], collapse = " ") 
      # capture all vector elements up to the first set of 3 asterisks
      # capture file information and who gave each of the speeches
  }else{
    list.speeches[[i]] <- paste(speech[x[i-1]:x[i]], collapse = " ")}
}     # capture the info between each set of subsequent indices 
      # capture all rows of each speech (currently separated by ***)
      #        place each complete speech in a different list position
```